# How to add a parameter to req.body in nodejs and Mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, mongodb

```
const { json } = require('body-parser');

const express = require('express');

const Signupdetails = require('../Model/Signupdetails');


const router = express.Router();


const signup = require('../Model/Signupdetails');


router.post('/' ,(req,res) => {

    const signupdetails = new Signupdetails(req.body)



    email = req.body.email

    user = email.substring(0,email.lastIndexOf("@")) 


    signupdetails.save() . then ( data => {

        res.status(200).json(data);

    })


    .catch (err => {

        res.json({ message : err });

    });

});



module.exports = router ;
```

I want to add a user to the save (). I tried using `user.save()` that didn't work

Comment: Your question doesn't really make sense. The request body contains data you get *from the client*. If you want to add something to it, then it should be added on the client. (If you want to pass data around on the server then you should use some other mechanism).

Comment: Please read the formatting help next to the question editor. There are tools for presenting code in a more readable way then what you ahve done there.

Comment: Get a tool like eslint which will warn you when you create implicit globals (which you do here and which can cause all sorts of problems).

Answer (score 0):

Your variable signupdetails has some syntax problems.
First in your route you have to store all the details from the sign up (as you model is built) in a variable, then you do a try and catch with a variable to represent your action in this case is savedDetails and equal to the variable(newSignup) you stored the details.save()
Should be more like this, I will give you an example with a async function.

Asyn functions are mostly what I use for routes. but feel free to do it somehowelse.

Good luck

```
router.post('/' , async (req,res) => {

    const newSignup= new Signupdetails({    //VARIABLE FOR THE DETAILS
         email = req.body.email
         user = email.substring(0,email.lastIndexOf("@"))
});

   try {
    const savedDetails = await newSignup.save();         //TRY AND CATCH
    res.send("All good");
   } catch(err) {
    res.status(400).send(err);
   }

}),
```